# VLOOKUP string from table that has characters between the string

Tags: excel, string, vlookup

I am trying to lookup a value e.g. `123abc456` from a table but the column that I want to look up will have the format e.g. `123-abc456` or `123ab-c456`.
There may be a dash between the characters in the string but these characters may be anywhere in the string. Is there a way of searching in excel using vlookup for the string `123abc456` without going through each record in my lookup table and removing the characters?
If there is another function in excel that would achieve this outcome then I am happy to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example assumes a formula in B2, looking at a value with a dash in A2, and a lookup table of values without dashes in Sheet 2, cells A2:B8:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",""),Sheet2!$A$2:$B$8,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

i'd get rid of '-' with `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")`, then look up from this trimmed column